# Sorting modified preorder traversal mysql tree

Tags: mysql, tree, sorting, traversal

Hey, I've implemented a tree in a mysql table using:

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

This is the method where you have a table like:

```
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+
| category_id | name                 | lft | rgt |
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+
|           1 | ELECTRONICS          |   1 |  20 |
|           2 | TELEVISIONS          |   2 |   9 |
|           3 | TUBE                 |   3 |   4 |
|           4 | LCD                  |   5 |   6 |
|           5 | PLASMA               |   7 |   8 |
|           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |  10 |  19 |
|           7 | MP3 PLAYERS          |  11 |  14 |
|           8 | FLASH                |  12 |  13 |
|           9 | CD PLAYERS           |  15 |  16 |
|          10 | 2 WAY RADIOS         |  17 |  18 |
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+
```

To print the table out like normal, you would just orderby the lft column. Is there any easy way to order it in reverse, or have another column like "cost" where all entries of the same "depth" are ordered by cost?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The URL you quote shows how to get a `SELECT` that gives the depth -- if you nest that into another `SELECT`, you can order as you prefer. For example:

```
SELECT thename, thedepth
FROM (
  SELECT node.name AS thename, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS thedepth
  FROM nested_category AS node,
  nested_category AS parent
  WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
  GROUP BY node.name
  ORDER BY node.lft) plain
ORDER BY thedepth DESC;
```

Similarly, of course, you could have a `node.cost AS thecost` as well in the inner `SELECT`, get it in the outer `SELECT`, and `ORDER BY thedepth DESC, thecost ASC` or whatever.

Performance may or may not be decent, but you can really tell only by trying (and `EXPLAIN SELECT` and adding appropriate indices;-).

If you have a sufficiently-smart DB engine, you don't need the nesting -- you can directly `ORDER BY` a computed column (as `thedepth` is here). But I think this solution would work on more/older DB engines/versions.

Comment: In the above example, nested_category AS parent is making the entire table named "parent". If I only wanted a sub section of the table, would I use a third select? Like:

(SELECT name, left, rgt FROM comments WHERE tree_id = 2) AS parent

Comment: What's "comments"? is it the same table I named "node"? If so, best s to add 'AND parent.tree_id = 2' to the WHERE. (btw, why the thanks without upvote nor acceptance? weird by normal SO etiquette!-).